# Copying parts of a line within a specific context using bash

Tags: bash, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To Find a Particular line and copying a specific content within the line using bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513155/to-find-a-particular-line-and-copying-a-specific-content-within-the-line-using-b)

I have a file `system.mss`  which contains blocks of information like this one:

```
BEGIN lmb_bram_if_ctnlr
PARAMETER INSTANCE = ilmb_cntlr_0
PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.00.b
PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000
PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x0003ffff
BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = ilmb_0
BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = ilmb_cntlr_0_BRAM_PORT
END
```

I want to copy the value for `PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR` into another file, but only for this kind of block; there are other blocks in the file, starting with different `BEGIN` lines, I want to ignore.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what's the result look like.

Comment: And please add to the question the additional information which is now hidden in comments to one of the answers.

Comment: Double post, actually, it seems – differences in the question are only due to my edits.

Answer (score 2):

> That is what `grep` is for

Actually, no, that is what `sed` is for.  More specifically, the range addressing mode of `sed` is ideally suited to just this type of problem.

```
sed -n '/BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntrl/,/END/s/PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = //p' system.mss
```

Meaning, in a range of lines starting with the first regex and ending with the last, perform the following action; if `PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR =` is found, remove it and print the line.

Comment: Much better than my approach – I keep telling myself I should delve into `sed` some day :).

Answer (score 1):

*Although the approach in my answer works, a better one is to use `sed` as per [@tripleee’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10512100/990363).*

That is what `grep` is for. To get the values of `PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR` inside `BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntrl` blocks of 8 lines length total only, do:

```
grep 'BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntrl' -A 7 "path/to/system.mss" | grep 'PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR' | cut -d = -f 2- > "path/to/outfile"
```

will write the values into `outfile` in the sequence in which they are found, i.e.

```
0x0003ffff
0x0000ffff
```

– note there will be a leading space on each line. If that bothers you, add

```
| cut -c 2-
```

before writing out to file.

Comment: You mean you need only the values for some specific `ilmb_cntlr_x` values?

Comment: No , actually there are other instances like a 'debug module' that will have a 'PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR'. I want only those that start with "BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr
 PARAMETER INSTANCE = ilmb_cntlr_0
 PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.00.b
 PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000
 PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x0003ffff
 BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = ilmb_0
 BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = ilmb_cntlr_0_BRAM_PORT
END"

Comment: Only those that are under "BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr"

Comment: Is the number of lines per block constant?

Comment: and there can 'n' of such "BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr"

Comment: That is not an issue. Please answer the question in my previous comment: do your `BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntrl` blocks always have the same number of lines?

Comment: yes the lines within "BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr" and "END" will be constant. 6 lines will be between them and "PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = (address)" will be on the 4th line in between them