# To Find a Particular line and copying a specific content within the line using bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have a file system.mss some of the contents of the file are :

`BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr`
`PARAMETER INSTANCE = dlmb_cntlr_0`
`PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.00.b`
`PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000`
`PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x0003ffff`
`BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = dlmb_0`
`BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = calmb_0_BRAM_PORTA`
`END`

`BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr`
`PARAMETER INSTANCE = ilmb_cntlr_0`
`PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.00.b`
`PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000`
`PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x0003ffff`
`BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = ilmb_0`
`BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = ilmb_cntlr_0_BRAM_PORT`
`END`

`BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr`
`PARAMETER INSTANCE = dlmb_cntlr_1`
 `PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.00.b`
 `PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000`
 `PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x0000ffff`
 `BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = dlmb_1`
 `BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = calmb_1_BRAM_PORTA`
`END`

`BEGIN lmb_bram_if_cntlr`
`PARAMETER INSTANCE = ilmb_cntlr_1`
 `PARAMETER HW_VER = 3.00.b`
 `PARAMETER C_BASEADDR = 0x00000000`
 `PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = 0x0000ffff`
 `BUS_INTERFACE SLMB = ilmb_1`
 `BUS_INTERFACE BRAM_PORT = ilmb_cntlr_1_BRAM_PORT`
`END`

I want to copy the 'PARAMETER C_HIGHADDR = (value)' only for ' PARAMETER INSTANCE = ilmb_cntlr_n'

Note: There can be 'n' number of such contents but i want to copy the address for only the ilmb_cntlr

How can i do That?

and once the address is copied ' for example 0x0003ffff i want it to be copied as 0x0003FFB0'

the last two ff are replace by B0

and any other 'f's are replaced by 'F' and rest of the address remains same

How can i do that?

Comment: I have very little experience with bash scripting , so please very specific

Comment: You already asked that question some hours ago : http://goo.gl/9LJh9
If you want to modify the question, just edit your post, don't post the same thing with the same title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying parts of a line within a specific context using bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510121/copying-parts-of-a-line-within-a-specific-context-using-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bash solution:

```
while read line ; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^PARAMETER\ INSTANCE\ =\ ilmb_cntlr_[0-9] ]] ; then
        found=1
    fi
    if [[ $line =~ ^PARAMETER\ C_HIGHADDR\ =\  ]] ; then
        value=$line
    fi
    if [[ $line = '' ]] ; then                      # end of block
        if (($found)) ; then                        # we are interested in the block
            value=${value//f/F}                     # capitalize f's
            echo ${value%FF}B0                      # replace last two characters with B0
        fi
        unset found                                 # reset variables so we can check the next block
        unset value
    fi
done
```

I would rather use Perl for a task like this, though.

Comment: how do i do this for the system.mhs file??

Comment: i only want the changed address to be copied , and no changes made to the system.mss file

Comment: how do i paste the changed address into another file?

Comment: Save the script into a file, say `extract.sh`. Run it as `/full/path/to/extract.sh /full/path/to/system.mss > /full/path/to/new.output`. The script makes no changes to the original file (if you do not understand why, you should start with some tutorials).

Comment: I recommend putting regex patterns in variables so you don't have to do awkward escaping.

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the code you gave me               error: unexpected end of line

Comment: i think there are errors in your code , can you please correct it      @choroba

Comment: I am sorry. The invocation line is wrong. Run it as `extract.sh < system.mss > new.output` (there was < missing).

Comment: i think there is some problem in the code because i ran it as above , it still says 'error line 17: unexpected end of line'                        @choroba

Comment: You should also include `#!/bin/bash` as the very first line of the script.

Comment: actually i want to use this code within another bash script ,how can i do that?  should i start the code with 'line= "system.mss"  @choroba

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb or maybe I didn't understand your need but why don't you make a loop with grep and cut inside it ?

Comment: if i knew how to do it , i would have already done it. I am totally new to this

Comment: please help i have a deadline tomorrow @choroba

Comment: This question violates the SO terms. You can't ask folks to do your homework. You need to hit the books, the web and the console hard. If something puzzles you, seek help but don't ask people to do your work, you will never learn to be successful this way.